# Наголос у слові автопокришка

Tags: наголос

Слово автопокришка складається з двох частин, друга з яких, вживана окремим словом, має наголос на першому складі: *п**о**кришка* (див. [словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)).
На сайті [Культура мови](http://kultura-movy.wikidot.com/nagolos#toc0) наводиться як правильний наголос *автопокр**и**шка*.

Чому наголос "з'їхав" на наступний склад?

Comment: Гм, УЛІФ пише, що може і _[покри́шка](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=покришка)_, але _чомусь_ розріжнӓё від _по́кришка_, цебто, до прикладу, _[алфа́ві́т](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=алфавіт)_ не рожрізнӓё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Словник труднощів української мови» (1989, під ред. Єрмоленко С.Я.) [пише наступне](http://bookre.org/reader?file=1341527&pg=237):

> **ПО́КРИШКА — ПОКРИ́ШКА.**
>   Розрізняються значенням.
>   **По́кришка**, -и, *дав.* -шці, *род. мн.* -шок. Предмет, яким накривається що-небудь зверху; кришка. *Мама накрила горщик покришкою.*
>   **Покри́шка**, -и, *дав*. -шці, *род. мн.* -шок. Футляр із товстої гуми, який надівається на камеру автомашини, велосипеда та ін. для захисту від пошкодження. *Покришка на колеса.*

У «Словнику-довіднику з культури української мови» тих самих авторів, та вже 2006 року, ця стаття повторюється слово-в-слово. СУМ-11 [дає це слово](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokryshka) з наголосом на першому складі в обох значеннях, це том 7, виданий у 1975 році.
Як бачимо, новіші джерела розрізняють два значення наголосом. Як на мене, росіянський вплив досить імовірний.

Answer (score -2):

Позаяк:

> Наголос у словах української мови складно правильно визначити, бо він не тільки може припадати на будь-який склад, але йому також властива рухомість – можлива зміна наголосу при відмінюванні слова.

— виходить, обидва варіанти правильні, існують лише особливі правила для певних типів слів.

Джерело - [ЗНО клуб](https://znoclub.com/mova-ta-literatura/535-yak-pravilnonagoloshuvati-slova-printsipi-nagoloshuvannya-problemni-vipadki.html)

Comment: Рухомість инодї арґументуётьсӓ. Наприклад приросток *ви-* маё властивість перетӓгувати наголос на себе. Отож хтїв би детальнїшу відповідь чи **приклади**. Тут можна зачепитисӓ за _складне слово_ через **‑о-**, або, точнїше, такого собі приростка **авто-**: особисто знаӱ, що наголос перетӓгуётьсӓ до останӧї частини, цебто корнӓ, але чи завше змінӱё наголос?

Comment: Зазначу, що з того, що наголос у словах української мови **загалом** може припадати на будь-який склад і йому властива рухомість, ажніяк не випливає, що **в кожному конкретному слові** дозволені обидва (всі) варіанти.

Comment: @Follower кумедна у Вас писанина. Трохи незрозуміла, але все ж.